# Running a function in a VueJs 2 component once its loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How do I fetch data once a component has been mounted? 
I start my vue instance and then load in the component, the component template loads in fine but the function calls in mounted are never run so the stats object remains empty, in turn, causing errors in the component/template that requires the data.

So how do I run a certain function on component load?

For what its worth... the functions I want to call will all make REST requests but each component will be running different requests.

```
Vue.component('homepage', require('./components/Homepage.vue'), {
  props: ["stats"],
  mounted: function() {
    this.fetchEvents();
    console.log('afterwards');
  },
  data: {
    loading: true,
    stats: {}
  },
  methods: {
    fetchEvents: function() {
      this.$http.get('home/data').then(function(response) {
        this.stats = response.body;
        this.loading = false;
      }, function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  }
});

const vue = new Vue({
  el: '#main',
  mounted: function() {
    console.log('main mounted');
  }
});
```

Comment: You are passing 3 parameters to your component but `Vue.component` only takes 2 parameters, the id and the definition: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-component

Comment: @craig_h ahh I see, I'm following the Laravel convention of loading in components https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/app.js like here. So how would I call mounted on the components?

Comment: It's fine to load your components with require, but your view model  (basically all the code you have added as the third paramater) should be in `Homepage.vue`. Take a look at [single file components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) to see how they work.

Answer (score 1):

You are already doing it fine by putting all the initialization stuff into `mounted`. The reason your component is not refreshing is probably because of binding of `this`, as explained below:

In your `fetchEvents` function, your `$http` success handler provides a response, which you are attempting to assign to `this.stats`. But it fails because `this` points to that anonymous function scope and not to Vue component.

To overcome this issue, you may use arrow functions as shown below:

```js
fetchEvents: function() {
  this.$http.get('home/data').then(response => {
    this.stats = response.body;
    this.loading = false;
  }, error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

Arrow functions do not create its own scope or `this` inside. If you use `this` inside the arrow function as shown above, it still points to Vue component, and therefore your component will have its data updated.

Note: Even the error handler needs to use arrow function, so that you may use `this` (of Vue component) for any error logging.

Comment: the mounted: in the component just doesn't seem to trigger at all, I have tried doing a simple console.log and even another function calling an alert but none of them fire. It seems when the component is loaded its not calling anything in the mounted function list.

Comment: Can you check this jsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/mani04/0gsq2ez1/ - here the `mounted` gets triggered and you can see the message in console. Are you sure you are using Vue 2.x latest version? And also, I do not know what you are trying to do with `require('./components/Homepage.vue')`, I have never come across that type of usage or requirement till now.

Comment: I'm simply following the code in Laravel and thats how they call the component, take a look here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/app.js

Comment: In that example, the component definition is entirely contained inside `./components/example.vue` ([link to example.vue](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/resources/assets/js/components/Example.vue)). But in your case, you are attempting to provide the definition directly again, after linking to `Homepage.vue`. You will have to either provide reference to the component vue file, or provide the component definition directly as shown in my jsFiddle example.